# Https request call capture in Wireshark

Tags: windows, wireshark

I have installed Wireshark and Windows based application(to be analyzed) which uses https request authentication to validate user.When I use interfaces -- > capture all the request of my system is captured but oathu https request in not found from Wireshark captures.

Please help me to find what's went wrong.

**Steps followed.**

```
Installed windows based application which is to be analyzed.

Wireshark interface --> capture started  and it is capturing packets.

Started Windows Application -->login page -> username and password are entered --> submitted for Authentication.

Authentication goes to oauth-some-url.com(some:iurl:ip:address) and comes back to Application as Successful Login.

Wireshark just stopped and saved all captures

Searched for (some:iurl:ip:address) but no captures found for that IP from Wireshark logs.
```

Comment: What capture mode was Wireshark in? 
What Interface were you capturing from?
Does the App allready know your login credentials? (e.a. could it have them 'saved' for future use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Capture mode was in Ethernet,App can't save credentials locally.

Comment: try capturing in promiscuous mode and all devices, maybe that it will show up.

Comment: Thanks for guidance,I tried capture on all interfaces and use promiscuous.After that saved captured file ,opened in a text editor searched for host ip(some:iurl:ip:address).but no use.

Comment: Could there be a way such calls escaping from Wireshark captures ?

Comment: Normally wireshark captures all.  When captured, try to put a filter on your display for traffic over port 443 (tcp.port eq 443).  Else, you're maybe surfing over WIFI and capturing ethernet?